# UIImage size in pixels

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Can I get the pixel size for a UIImage if I just multiply the image.size with the image.scale ? Is it the same as doing this:

```
   guard let cgImage = image.CGImage else{
        return nil
    }
    let width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

`CGImageGetWidth` and `CGImageGetHeight` will return the same size (in pixels) as returned by `image.size * image.scale`.

Comment: Swift 5: `CGImage.witdth` and `CGImage.height`

Answer (score 6):

You can, but it **isn't the same** as cgImage.width x cgImage.height (the new names for the CG functions you gave). The cgImage doesn't know about at least some EXIF flags that might have rotated or flipped the original image. You can see a difference in image Portrait_5.jpg through Portrait_8.jpg at https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples. `image.size.height * image.scale` gives 1800, but `cgImage.height` gives 1200 (really the width).

Comment: So, it _is_ the same **up to orientation**? i.e., at worst, width and height are flipped?

Comment: Yes. You could imagine some exif "scaling" flag that the CGImage also doesn't know about, but I don't believe one exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageSizeInPixel() -> CGSize {
        let heightInPoints = size.height
        let heightInPixels = heightInPoints * scale

        let widthInPoints = size.width
        let widthInPixels = widthInPoints * scale

        return CGSize(width: widthInPixels, height: heightInPixels)
    }
}
```